# SVN Checkout through Jenkins pipeline failing with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

**Jenkins Version: 2.303.3**

**Pipeline: SCM Step Version: 2.13**

We're checking out SVN code using `Pipeline SCM Step` plugin like below -

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', 
         excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '',
         filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '',
         locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, credentialsId: '<credential-id>',                                                                    
         depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true,
         local: '<folder-to-checkout>', remote: '<path-to-checkout>]], quietOperation: true,
         workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateWithCleanUpdater']])
```

But this checkout results into below error -

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1393)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1348)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1094)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.createChangeLogParser(SubversionSCM.java:1539)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.onCheckout(WorkflowRun.java:871)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.access$1000(WorkflowRun.java:137)
        at 

org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowRun.java:1168)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:155)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I googled this error but unable to find any solution related to Jenkins plugin. Could you please help to understand what could be issue here?

Answer (score 4):

Updating the Subversion plugin should fix this error. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).